# Django nginx/uwsgi - first request is very slow

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

I am having a problem with nginx or uwsgi.

When I enter site after some time of unactivity or after a service restart the first request is always very slow.

From uwsgi logs I got info that first request takes about 3000-4000ms, and other requests take about 30-50ms.

I am just guessing that there's a problem with uwsgi workers.

I'll paste additional config a bit later.

How do I track down this bug? What could be the cause of the problem?

Comment: One can only tell after you have updated the question with your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

it is expected as django is 'lazy': the whole app is basically loaded at the first request.

Comment: Please add a relevant documentation link and expand more on the laziness.

Comment: afaik there are no official django docs about it, it is the way it works. 'Lazy' is a standard technical term to define an application that fully loads at the first request instead of startup. I have seen someone calling wget/curl soon after app startup to trigger a full load, or people directly calling the WSGI entry point soon after startup. In my opinion none of this approaches work well, you should invest in a better reloading strategy.

Comment: Why don't you add that to your answer then?